# Rename None in index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Hi i am trying to rename a series index and replace None with 'Test' value.
I am doing:

```
df = (df_fonds
                .groupby('Article', dropna=False)['ActifEur'].sum()
                .rename({None : 'Test'})
                )
```

I also did:

```
df_sfdr = (df_fonds
                .groupby('Article', dropna=False)['ActifEur'].sum()
                .rename({np.nan : 'Test'})
                )
```

```
df_sfdr = (df_fonds
                .groupby('Article', dropna=False)['ActifEur'].sum()
                .rename({'NaN' : 'Test'})
                )
```

but the results are still None in the index. Is it coded as None or others things ?
Result that I get:

```
Article
Article 6    500
Article 8    100
Article 9    120
NaN          10
Name: ActifEur, dtype: float64
```

Any help will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Convert the Series to a DataFrame and then use the fillna() method:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['Article'] = df['Article'].fillna('Test')
df.set_index('Article', inplace=True)
```

or directly

```
df = df.rename(index={idx: 'Test' for idx in df.index if pd.isna(idx)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a issue to me but nonetheless you can fill the null values with `test` before doing groupby

```
(
    df_fonds
    .fillna({'Article': 'Test'})
    .groupby('Article', dropna=False)['ActifEur'].sum()
)
```